# How to conditionally match and replace words in a statement using regex in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regexp-replace

I wonder if there's anyway to make "switch" replaces in RegEx.

For example, string:

> round square unknown liquid

And pattern is: `\w+`

And **imaginary** replacement something like:

> if (round) then "Ball" else if (square) then "Box" else if (liquid)
> then "Water" else if (hot) then "Fire"

And result would be

> Ball Box unknown Water

The idea is to use only patterns and replacements, without any C# code.

Details or clarity:

```
var Text = "round square unknown liquid";
    
var Pattern = @"\w+";
var Replacement = @"if (round) then Ball else if (square) then Box else if (liquid) then Water else if (hot) then Fire"; // <-- is this somehow possible?

var Result = new Regex(Pattern).Replace(Text, Replacement);

Console.WriteLine(Result);
```

Expected output:

> Ball Box unknown Water

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed not possible and it should not bother you that it is not possible.

Is it possible to build a submarine just from paper? No. Just need to add a few ingredients.

But were it not for the "only pure regex" constraint, this is what I would have done:

```
var dictionaryReplace = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"round","Ball"},
    {"square","Box"},
    {"liquid","Water"},
    {"hot","Fire"}, 
};

var Text = "round square unknown liquid";

var Pattern = $"({string.Join("|", dictionaryReplace.Keys)})"; //(round|square|liquid|hot)
var Result = new Regex(Pattern).Replace(Text, x => dictionaryReplace[x.Value]);

Console.WriteLine(Result); //Ball Box unknown Water
```

Comment: The answer "not possbille" is sufficient also. I just wanted to be sure I'm not missing anything, as regex functionality is vast and has lots of advanced methods.